# Checking for updating mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I need help with my project. I've made some swing java app which allowed to users make some operations with database (deleting, adding, inserting etc). Then this app has 2 roles, for whom who made the change (delete,add,insert into database) and for whom who check it. So for users who check, I have to make smth which alarm them, like "this user added smth to this table now". So I have no idea how to realise it, first of all I think I should write smth for check database changes like every minute? Like  ScheduledExecutorService? Maybe. But I don't know how to check it for changes? For example i have table employee, it has columns like: name, surname, tel.number, salary. For example some user change salary from 100 to 200. So how it checks this table for changing? Maybe someone could show me example? Because I couldn't find it, I couldn't do it for 2 days. Please! Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I think each JDBC will support this function. For example Oracle supports it.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815

Comment: The alternative is to poll the database using a `javax.swing.Timer`.